# Mapping JSON to Java objects with different keywords

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My company has a webserver API that provides search results in JSON format. I'm responsible for developing an Android app that consumes that API, and I have made some classes that model the objects in the JSON responses.

For the sake of habit and my own preference, I use to write my code in English only. However, most of the JSON keys are not in English. This way, I cannot readily use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the JSON strings into Java Objects -- at least that is what I think.

I was wondering if there is any way to reference just once per class the connection between the JSON key and their corresponding instance variables in the code. In a way that after referenced, I could simply instantiate objects from JSON and create JSON strings from objects.

Is that possible?

Example:

```
// Java code
class Model {
    String name;
    Integer age;
}

// JSON with keys in Portuguese
{
    "nome" : "Mark M.",      # Key "nome" matches variable "name"
    "idade" : 30             # Key "idade" matches variable "age"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@SerializedName` annotation.

Here is an example of how this annotation is meant to be used:

```
 public class SomeClassWithFields {
   @SerializedName("name") private final String someField;
   private final String someOtherField;

   public SomeClassWithFields(String a, String b) {
     this.someField = a;
     this.someOtherField = b;
   }
 }
```

The following shows the output that is generated when serializing an instance of the above example class:

```
 SomeClassWithFields objectToSerialize = new SomeClassWithFields("a", "b");
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String jsonRepresentation = gson.toJson(objectToSerialize);
 System.out.println(jsonRepresentation);
```

===== OUTPUT =====

```
 {"name":"a","someOtherField":"b"}
```

Source: [SerializedName Javadocs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Comment: That seems to be precisely what I need.